# Git post commit with python

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, hook, githooks

Is it possible with a post commit hook to feed all the filename with path of each added or modified files to a python script?

I found some usefull library but they require to search in the repository.
like this one : https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html
I want git to automatically communicate those filenames to my script.

Thanks.

## EDIT

Apparently I canget the last commit hash with :
git rev-parse --verify HEAD

Then I can get the file list of this commit with
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only

however I only want the modified and added files, not the deleted ones.

## EDIT2

Well I did not understood correctly what were git hooks.
Apparently I can put a python script in the hook folders and it will be executed.

All I have to do now is find a way to speak to git in bash from my python script to get my file list.

Forget this post.

## EDIT3

Here are the commands I'm looking for:
getting the last commit hash :

```
git log -n 1 HEAD --pretty=format:"%H"
```

output example :

```
$ git log -n 1 HEAD --pretty=format:"%H"
42e6783eeda7ff56a02eab07f1ec4ba6e19212b6
```

getting the file list of this commit with information about their modification:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-status <hash>
```

output example :

```
$ git show --pretty="format:" --name-status 42e6783eeda7ff56a02eab07f1ec4ba6e19212b6
M       admin/flexAdmin/src/main/flex/business/AdminController.as
D       admin/flexAdmin/src/main/flex/linky/business/command/GetContenuFamilleATCommand.as
D       admin/flexAdmin/src/main/flex/linky/business/event/GetContenuFamilleATEvent.as
M       admin/flexAdmin/src/main/flex/model/ModelLocator.as
```

Comment: If you find that your question no longer needs to be answered, then you can delete it. Note that the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) recommends running `git log -1 HEAD` to get information about the most recent commit.

Comment: I saw a lot of people asking about those 2 command so I'll leave the post

Comment: Just in the case if you ever think needing pre-commit hook I made some related work here with Python: https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/blob/master/vvv/hooks/git.py

Comment: If you want to keep the question open, then at least post your solution as an *answer* so that others can more easily recognized that the question will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this kind of thing you have to make a python script and place it in the hook folder of the git repository, name your script post-commit.

Well that is the theory but I did not try yet, I just wrote this script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python   1
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import subprocess
import sys, os

DELETED_FILE_TOKEN = "D\t"

def execute_cmd(full_cmd, cwd=None):
    """Execute a git command"""

    process = subprocess.Popen(full_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=cwd)
    (stdoutdata, stderrdata) = process.communicate(None)
    if 0 != process.wait():
        raise Exception("Could not execute git command")

    return (stdoutdata.strip(), stderrdata.strip())

def get_last_commit_hash():
    """Get the hash of the last commited commit"""
    return execute_cmd("git log -n 1 HEAD --pretty=format:\"%H\"")[0]

def get_commit_file_list(hash):
    """Get the list of files impacted by a commit, each file is preceded by
    x\t where x can be A for added, D for deleted, M for modified"""
    file_list = execute_cmd("git show --pretty=\"format:\" --name-status "+hash)[0]
    return file_list.split("\n");

def remove_unwanted_files(file_list):
    """remove the x\t from the file names and remove the file that have
    been deleted"""
    cleaned_file_list = list()
    for file in file_list:
        if not file[:2] == DELETED_FILE_TOKEN:
            cleaned_file_list.append(file[2:])
    return cleaned_file_list

def get_script_current_path():
    """get the scrypt current path (to lacalise the repository and open files)"""
    pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    return os.path.abspath(pathname)    

def get_hash():
    """Allow you to launch the script in command line with any hash"""
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    return sys.argv[1]
else:
    return get_last_commit_hash()

hash = get_hash();
file_list = get_commit_file_list(hash)
file_list = remove_unwanted_files(file_list)

#here file_list contains the modified and added files
```